# didn't assign model.fit, can I plot the history?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Can I plot accuracy, loss... if I didn't assign model.fit to something.
I just wrote model.fit and trained the model.

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible after training the model. You will need that `History` object to plot the loss or accuracy vs. time graph.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this without a history in keras:

1. take the text output of the keras training and manually take the loss values of every epoch and do the plot by hand by filling 2 numpy arrays with the values ( one for the loss and an other for the validation loss).

This seems a long task but with a text editor like visual studio code it's a matter of seconds.

2. write a callback that after every epoch writes the result of the epoch on an external text file and then take the values in a similar way as point 1.

something like this:

```
class print_log_Callback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, logpath, steps):
    self.logpath = logpath
    self.losslst = np.zeros(steps)

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    with open(logpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("The average loss for epoch {} is {:7.2f} and val_loss is {:7.2f}.".format(epoch, logs["loss"], logs['val_loss']))
        writefile.write("\n")
        print("The mean train loss is: ", np.mean(self.losslst))
        writefile.write("\n")
        writefile.write("\n")
```